# How to turn a proccess on again

Tags: windows-7, window, aero, transparency

I turned off "dwm.exe" proccess which is responsible for transparent / opaque Windows in Windows 7. How to turn it on again quick (without restarting the system)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the windows service that adds all the snazzy areo effects. To start it, open the Services from Control Panel and then find the "Desktop Window Manager Session Manager" service in the list.  Click the start button to start the service.

Comment: Alternately, `Run->sc start UxSms`

Answer (score 0):

You can always just press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, or if that doesn't work <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and then `File` > `New Task`. This is how you can start any process.

Comment: I don’t think that you can just run `dwm.exe`. It’s better to actually run the service with the MMC snap-in or service controller.